# Why can't I save two or more siblings with mongoid-tree?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I'm using this engine: https://github.com/opennorth/popolo-engine

As you can see in the [model](https://github.com/opennorth/popolo-engine/blob/master/app/models/popolo/organization.rb), `organization` includes `Mongoid::Tree`.

For whatever reason, I cannot seem to create/save more than one record on a level.

I can have two organisations, one a parent and one a child, but I can't then add a second child. I also cannot have two 'top level' nodes that sit without parents.

```
Popolo::Organization.create(name:"Org1")
 => #<Popolo::Organization _id: 5405dd09360e2e5421000002, created_at: 2014-09-02 15:06:49 UTC, updated_at: 2014-09-02 15:06:49 UTC, parent_id: nil, parent_ids: [], name: "Org1", classification: nil, founding_date: nil, dissolution_date: nil, image: nil> 

Popolo::Organization.create(name:"Org2")
 => #<Popolo::Organization _id: 5405dd0c360e2e5421000003, created_at: 2014-09-02 15:06:52 UTC, updated_at: 2014-09-02 15:06:52 UTC, parent_id: nil, parent_ids: [], name: "Org2", classification: nil, founding_date: nil, dissolution_date: nil, image: nil> 

Popolo::Organization.all.size
 => 1
```

EDIT: This works okay in the test environment.

Comment: Did you try `create!` instead of `create` to make sure there is no validation error?

Comment: Yes, tried that & no validation errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I restarted my mongodb service and it worked!

`sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock
service mongodb start`

Very odd indeed.